# Determining Virtual Directory for wcf services

Tags: .net, wcf, installation

I have built building the install msi’s for a wcf services. In one case the virtual directory is “setup”. This is not what I want but I don’t know where it is coming from and I don’t know how to change it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on The Setup Project

Choose View - File System

Right-Click on Web Application Folder

Choose Properties Window

You can now change the virtual Directory